# Series protection resistors on I2C lines

Tags: i2c

In [NXP's I2C specification and user manual Rev. 7](https://www.pololu.com/file/0J435/UM10204.pdf), it states we can put series resistors on SDA and SCL lines for protection against high-voltage spikes:

[image]

And it gives a graph, to show the relation between Rs and Rp:

[image]

I wonder how NXP get this graph, if there is a closed form equation to show the relation between Rs and Rp?

Comment: SDA and SCL pin does have it's own capacitance (which limits switching speed), and Rs additionally limits charging current. I think they've calculated that figure from condition that allows to switch with needed speed (just as Rp calculates for long lines).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

R<sub>p</sub> and R<sub>s</sub> form a voltage divider. R<sub>s</sub> must be low enough to keep the voltage on the line below V<sub>IL</sub>-V<sub>nL</sub>. They must also be small enough to sink at least I<sub>OL</sub>.

We therefore have the following:

I<sub>s</sub> - I<sub>p</sub> >= 3mA

V<sub>s</sub> / V<sub>DD</sub> <= 0.2

V<sub>s</sub> + V<sub>p</sub> = V<sub>DD</sub>

Solving for these simultaneously results in the output shown in the chart.